# FBML: select one of the user's friends

Tags: facebook, random, fbml, friend

I'm designing an app based on FBML. I want to fetch a user's friends list and pick any one of them. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with graph API and `shuffle()`. Cheers!